# Charset is not working - Spanish characters

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding

This is really driving me crazy. I'm building a spanish website (meaning a lot of latin characters) and I'm using Zend framework.

When I save a `á` it displays like `&Atilde;&iexcl;` . I know is a charset encoding but I dont understand why.

My head charset is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` 
My database is `utf8_general_ci` . I've changed the charset to others and always the same problem.

When I look in my database, what is saved is an `á`

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: "Save" how? Where does this happen?

Comment: are you setting the names when connecting to the db? `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");`

Comment: I'm using Zend-DB to save to the databasae, so is like PDO

Comment: Everybody's focusing on the database, but the database does not HTML escape. So, again, where exactly does it turn into HTML entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the recipe to get rid of encoding headaches:

1. Your DB, tables and fields must use collation `utf8_unicode_ci`.
2. Be sure your code (HTML, PHP... *all*) is UTF-8 encoded.
3. Always use this `meta` tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
4. This is long:

If you have access to MySQL file configuration `my.cnf` just add this line:

```
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

This tells MySQL to return results in UTF-8 for each connection.

If you cannot edit `my.cnf` but you are using PDO, open the connection this way:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

If you aren't using PDO... *start* using it, what are you waiting for? Meanwhile you can execute this after each connection if you use ext/MySQLi:

```
$mysql->set_charset('utf8');
```

Or this if you use plain old ext/MySQL:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
```

Comment: Use `mysql_set_charset` for the old API, otherwise you can get into problems with `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Answer (score 0):

The character `á` and other characters outside the ASCII map can be mapped with `unicode`.

As you are stroing the data in a table with `UTF-8` charset and characters are storing properly.

I would suggest you that

- Before you store data
- Before you fetch data

Run the query `SET NAMES UTF-8`. This will fetch your `UTF-8` data with taking care of the characters which are outside of ASCII map.

While outputting the data you make sure that you are forcing/directing browser to use the `UTF-8` charset to print the data.